# VB 2010 Direct input with GamePad

Tags: .net, vb.net, joystick

I have a form with 2 labels on it, the first label displays the USB game pads name (once found) the second i want to display the button pushed, here's what i have so far:

```
 Imports Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput

Public Class Form1
Public _device As Device
Public _state As JoystickState
Public arm As Boolean = True


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim gameControllerList As DeviceList
    gameControllerList = Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly)

    If (gameControllerList.Count > 0) Then

        Dim deviceInstance As DeviceInstance
        label.Text = "Found"
        For Each deviceInstance In gameControllerList
            _device = New Device(deviceInstance.InstanceGuid)
            label.Text = deviceInstance.InstanceName
            _device.SetDataFormat(DeviceDataFormat.Joystick)
            Exit For
        Next
    Else
        label.Text = "not found"
    End If
    output.Clear()
    _device.Acquire()

    Call Poll()
End Sub


Public Sub Poll()
    Dim buttons() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    _device.Poll()
    _state = _device.CurrentJoystickState
    buttons = _state.GetButtons()
    Dim word As String
    word = BitConverter.ToString(buttons)
    output.AppendText(word)

End Sub
```

End Class

All i see are 0's on the output, which means the buttons being pushed on the keypad arent being detected

Anyone know how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: got it i needed a _device.Acquire() in there. Now thats done does anyone know how to detect buttons pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny enough, it's exactly like the error says: you need to acquire the device before beginning to poll it.

```
_device.Acquire();
```

Note that this only happens once before the actual polling function.

Comment: Yeah i just figured the same, would you know how to detect which keys are pushed?

Comment: Sure, once you have your `_state` (horrible naming scheme by the way), you call `GetButtons` which returns a `Byte()`. You then iterate over the buttons array and if it's not `0`, then it's pressed.

Comment: i see would i need to set _state.GetButtons() to a byte array

Dim buttons() as Byte
buttons = _state.GetButtons() 

would something like that work?

Comment: So i did as follows: 

        buttons = _state.GetButtons()
        Dim word As String
        word = BitConverter.ToString(buttons)
        output.AppendText(word)

when i run it i see a bunch of 0's, once i press a button it still remains 0's, am i doing something wrong that you can see?

Comment: Are you polling and getting the *current* state before every `GetButtons` call?

Comment: I have a button on the form and when i push it
1. a textbox is cleared
2. the device is acquired
3. Device is polled
4. current state is obtained

i have added my new code above

Comment: See that's why I made the last comment in my post. You shouldn't keep reinitializing the device over and over again, you initialize it once and then call `Poll` however many times you want.